# How to get the Id of each row of a table in AngularJs

Tags: angularjs

I have N number of rows in a table. When I click on the "save" button I need to get the "id" of each row.

Comment: Please provide anything more on your question, at least some codes you were working on...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply send `id` as the parameter of the function. For example if you call `sendId()` just send the parameter of `sendId(your_id_here)`.
Example:

```
<div ng-repeat="list in lists">
   <button ng-click="sendId(list.id)">
</div>
```

If you want to send index of current element:

```
<div ng-repeat="list in lists">
   <button ng-click="sendId($index)">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

> $index

is the row number inside your ng-repeat

Answer (score 0):

$index is for to get the index of collection in ngRepeat

if you use $index id starts from 0 or you can start id $index+1

Answer (score 0):

if you work with *ngFor, you can simply add at the end of the for loop `let i = index`